# How to connect a GUI button to function?

Tags: lua, roblox

I am developing a new Roblox game where you can setup and control you're own virtual machine using SurfaceGUIs on a modeled screen. I am trying to make a confirmation GUI
where if you click YES, then it starts the VM, and if you click NO, then it closes the GUI and doesn't start a VM. But when I click on NO, nothing happens! Here is my code:

```lua
local gui = script.Parent.Parent
local button = script.Parent

local function cancel()
    gui.Visible = false
end

button.Activated:Connect(cancel())
```

Please help!
P.S: The confirmation frame is in the ScreenGUI, the button is in the frame, and the LocalScript is in the button.

Comment: [This seems to be clearly explained in the documentation](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Creating-GUI-Buttons). Look in particular at how many parentheses are used in the `Connect()` call.

Comment: I just copyed the code from the docs to my code and made a few edits, and now it works! Thank you!

Comment: Please share your solution as an Answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of connecting your event to a **FUNCTION**, you are calling it.

I'll leave a sample on how to correctly use it

```
local Button = ... --where your button is located

local function Cancel()
  --code 
end

Button.MouseButton1Click:Conect(Cancel)
```

MouseButton1Click is an event which fires after the **GUI BUTTON** is clicked.