# How do I make buttons function on the cursors click in roblox studio?

Tags: gui, roblox

I would just like to know how to add buttons in roblox studio because when I play roblox and see all those great games with buttons that I can click! How do I make a button, and how do I make it work?

Comment: I never used Roblox, but perhaps [the very first Google result for "Roblox Button"](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Creating-GUI-Buttons) answers your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect a GUI button to function?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/183773/how-to-connect-a-gui-button-to-function)

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

According the the [Roblox developer website](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Creating-GUI-Buttons), you can create a button by right clicking in the Explorer window and clicking the button you want. There are two types of buttons as described on the website.

> **Text Button:** A TextButton is very similar to a TextLabel, except that a player can activate it with a click. Internally, it also shares
> many of the same visual properties as a text label — font, background
> color, stroke color, etc.
>
> **Image Button:** Similarly, an ImageButton is like an interactive version of the ImageLabel object and it uses a custom image that you
> upload to Roblox. It also shares most of the same properties as its
> non-button counterpart.

In order to add a function that occurs when a button is pressed, simply create a local script inside the button and add this code:

```
function leftClick()
    print("You can replace this line with any function you want on a left click.")
end
 
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(leftClick)
```

For more information on GUI buttons in Roblox, go to their official website [here](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/GuiButton).